# Read Binary string in Python, zlib

Tags: python, json, amazon-dynamodb, zlib, simplejson

I want to store a large JSON (dict) from Python in dynamoDB.

After some investigation it seems that zlib is the way to go to get compression at a good level. Using below Im able to encode the dict.

```
ranking_compressed = zlib.compress(simplejson.dumps(response["Item"]["ranking"]).encode('utf-8'))
```

The (string?) then looks like this: `b'x\x9c\xc5Z\xdfo\xd3...`.

I can directly decompress this and get the dict back with:

```
ranking_decompressed = simplejson.loads(str(zlib.decompress(ranking_compressed).decode('utf-8')))
```

All good so far. However, when putting this in dynamoDB and then reading it back using the same decompress code as above. The (string?) now looks like this:

```
Binary(b'x\x9c\xc5Z\xdf...
```

The error I get is:

```
 bytes-like object is required, not 'Binary'
```

Ive tried accessing the Binary with e.g. .data but I cant reach it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try if you can access the content of the `Binary` obnect with `.value`.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks! That did the trick :). Write an answer and Ill accept it!

Answer (score 2):

Boto3 `Binary` objects have a `value` property.

```py
# in general...
binary_obj.value
# for your specific case...
ranking_decompressed = simplejson.loads(str(zlib.decompress(response["Item"]["ranking_compressed"].value).decode('utf-8')))
```

Oddly, this seems to be documented nowhere except the source code for the Binary class [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/types.html#Binary)